# Using own server as primary DNS while forwarding unknown to AD DC

Tags: active-directory

I am working on setting up an Active Directory domain for my company. Looking through the documents, it seems that the DCs push themselves as the primary DNS servers to any clients. My boss is demanding that I find some way to use our existing DNS servers as the primary DNS host. I have not found any way at this point. Is there any way to use an alternate primary DNS host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, absolutely. Assuming your AD domain is ad.example.com, just create NS records for ad.example.com in your primary DNS servers pointing to the AD DNS hosts. That will allow your primary server to do what they've always done, while referring AD-related queries to your AD DNS servers.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I can't hit the accept button just yet. I will when it lets me though.